# Mocking confused with __init__.py module

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I'm currently trying to use mock to test a package. Mock seems to not like it when I structure my python modules in different directories using `__init__.py`

My file tree is as follows:

```
.\pkg
  |_ module
       |_ __init__.py
       |_ module.py
  |_ tests
       |_ __init__.py
       |_ test_basic.py
```

When I try to mock the methods inside filesize using the following unit test:

```
@mock.patch('module.os')
def test_filesize(self, mock_os):
    class file_info:
        st_size = 1000

    mock_os.path.isfile.return_value = True
    mock_os.stat.return_value = file_info

    output = self.response.file_size("filename")
```

I get an error with a traceback of:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_filesize (__main__.cl_test_build_search_url)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\mock\mock.py", line 1297, in patched
    arg = patching.__enter__()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\mock\mock.py", line 1369, in __enter__
    original, local = self.get_original()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\mock\mock.py", line 1343, in get_original
    "%s does not have the attribute %r" % (target, name)
AttributeError: <module 'module' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\work\\open_source\\pkg\\module\\__init__.py'> does not have the attribute 'os'
```

I have imported the os module in `module.py` but I think it's getting confused because the `__init__.py` is confusing the interpreter?

I've looked at the mock.patch arguments available and

`@mock.patch('module.os', create = True)`

allowed the code to run but os doesn't end up being mocked at all and `os.path.isfile` and `os.stat` doesn't get overridden during run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
@mock.patch('module.os', create = True)
```

to this:

```
# module(directory) module(module.py)
@mock.patch('module.module.os', create = True)
```

I am NOT good at explaining, here is a digest from `mock.py` explains:

> `target` should be a string in the form `'package.module.ClassName'`. The
>       `target` is imported and the specified object replaced with the `new`
>       object, so the `target` must be importable from the environment you are
>       calling `patch` from. The target is imported when the decorated function
>       is executed, not at decoration time.

Comment: I thought I already imported the module.py why do I need to give the full path again?

Comment: you have to mock where it is initialized which is in the other script thus you have to provide the full path

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add a little more to @Gang's answer, since this bit me. This is going to be a little confusing because of the above example names but...

Example from above:

```
.\pkg
  |_ module
       |_ __init__.py
       |_ module.py
  |_ tests
       |_ __init__.py
       |_ test_basic.py
```

Lets say in the `pkg.module.module` you have a class named `module` (same as the python file name)

*module.py*

```
from time import time

class module:
    pass
```

and in your pkg.module `__init__.py` you do something like

```
from .module import module

__all__ = (
    "module",
)
```

If you want to patch `time` in the `module.py`:

```
mock.patch("pkg.module.module.time", ...)
```

Mock will get confused/blocked by the `__init__.py` and give you an error like

```
E AttributeError: <class 'pkg.module.module.module'> does not have the attribute 'time'
```

I had to change the name of the file or class. Or even just change the case, in the example above.

```
from time import time

class Module:
    pass
```

***init**.py*

```
from .module import Module

__all__ = (
    "Module",
)
```